# Dump all Views of multiple databases in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I need to export the views from *multiple* databases of an older server. (Essentially, to generate a list of views using a particular piece of SQL Server)

The fastest way I've found thus far is to manually use the `Generate scripts` function to export the views to a file.

I feel like there is probably a better way I don't know about.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You can do this:

Click on `database --> tasks --> Generate Scripts -->`
Select " select objects", then, select views. 
It will create a script with all the views for the database. But, this works with one database at time.

Comment: I mentioned that in the original question because my question is about how to run that on multiple databases. When you have 100+, it can be tedious and error prone to do each one that way.

Comment: EXEC sp_msforeachdb can be used to run a task against each database, but I don't know the procedure SSMS calls behind the scenes to "Generate Scripts"

Comment: @Thronk please see [my comment below](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/105551/dump-all-views-of-multiple-databases-in-ms-sql/105561?noredirect=1#comment191796_105561) - sp_MSForEachDb is really not a good idea, even for one-offs, especially when you have 100+ databases and it won't be obvious if it happens to skip some of them.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - good to know.  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will certainly need the right permissions to view the views definition. This should work for you. Please note that I'm using the undocumented `sp_MSforeachdb` stored procedure. This means that it could change without notice so is not advisable to include as part of your production/live tsql code as it could fail. Check Aaron comment about it.

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb '
    IF DB_ID(''?'') > 4
    BEGIN
        USE [?]
        SELECT DB_NAME()
        SELECT  c.text
            FROM    sysobjects o
                    JOIN syscomments c
                        ON c.id = o.id
            WHERE   o.type = ''V'';
    END'
```

Comment: Please don't use `sp_MSForEachDb`. It's undocumented, unsupported, and known to unpredictably skip databases. I [wrote this replacement](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/) but it would need to be adjusted to work on SQL Server 2000.

Comment: Was editing when you posted your comment. At least it gives the OP a head start.

Answer (score 0):

May `information_schema` be your friend:

```
SELECT v.TABLE_SCHEMA AS View_Schema
    ,v.table_name AS View_Name
    ,v.VIEW_DEFINITION AS Create_View_Script
FROM information_schema.VIEWS v
JOIN information_schema.columns c ON v.table_schema = c.table_schema
    AND v.table_name = c.table_name
GROUP BY v.TABLE_SCHEMA
    ,v.table_name
    ,v.VIEW_DEFINITION
```

[image]

You need to run it once per each database

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the _from multiple databases_ part.

Comment: @mustaccio I added a phrase saying that the query should be run for each DB. Otherwise there is no other solution. Apart from the  undocumented, unsupported, and known to unpredictably skip databases `EXEC sp_MSforeachdb `

Answer (score -1):

Last statement is not correct if the View is too large, It will miss substentials data from the view.

use SQL statement generate script under task instead for the exact 100% export!

Comment: Welcome, this site is not run a like a forum.  Its questions and answers.  Therefore, please edit your answer to post a complete answer instead of an addendum